# Redux Form, values disappear on re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have a form, in this form a user is able to attach files. When the user removes a file, the state changes and the form re-renders. When this happens, all the values the user has entered disappear.

Is there a way to keep the values in the fields upon re-render?

I'm using redux-forms.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass the form "initial values". So, as the form is updated, you should be updating whatever holds your initial values in state. Then, once they remove a file, you can pass the initial values back in (what they previously entered) so that even if the form re-renders the values should persist.

https://redux-form.com/7.2.2/examples/initializefromstate/